# Show that the relation defined by "$x\mid y$" in an "integrity ring" is not symmetrical but can be antisymmetric

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that the relation defined by "$x\mid y$" in an "integrity ring" is not symmetrical but can be antisymmetric.

I know that the "$\mid$" relation is reflective and transitive but it's never symmetrical, because $(1\mid 0$, but $0\nmid 1)$ and it's not necessarily antisymmetrical [in $\mathbb{Z}$, ($2\mid-2$) and ($-2 \mid 2$);
but in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ it's already antisymmetrical]. (why?)

How can I use my above conjectures to show what is asked?

Comment: Technically, in the zero ring divisibility is a symmetric relation.

Comment: @Gae.S. But $\mid$ it can never be symmetrical. So, if it can never be symmetrical. Could the zero of the ring be? (how?)

Comment: In integral domains it isn't symmetric, because the zero ring is not a domain. But in rings it can be, because of that specific case.

Comment: @Gae.S. Really. But in the above case it is in a ring of integrity.

Comment: Does "integrity ring" mean integral domain?

Comment: @NoahSolomon, yes!